# Razor - unable to add System.Core to Web.Config

Tags: razor, servicestack-razor

I am using ServiceStack (self hosted) with Razor.

I have an issue trying to add System.Core to the namespaces in the web.config file.

Specifically, I get a compilation error if I include System.Core in the web.config.

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Core' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 12:     using System;
>   Line 13:     using System.Collections.Generic;
>   Line 14:     using System.Core;
>   Line 15:     using System.Data;
>   Line 16:     using System.IO;

Extract of Web.config file:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc" />
<pages pageBaseType="ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System" />
    <add namespace="System.Core" /> **-> THIS GIVES AN ERROR**
    <add namespace="System.Data" />
    <add namespace="System.Linq" />
    <add namespace="ServiceStack" />
    <add namespace="ServiceStack.Html" />
    <add namespace="ServiceStack.Razor" />
    <add namespace="ServiceStack.Text" />
    <add namespace="ServiceStack.OrmLite" />
    <add namespace="Classifieds" />
    <add namespace="Classifieds.ServiceModel" />
    <add namespace="Classifieds.ServiceInterface" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Core is not a namespace its is an assembly